# How to prevent syntastic from creating a directory for every vim instance?

Tags: vim, syntastic

When using the syntastic plugin with vim, I see a new `/tmp/vXXXXXXX` directory every time I open a new vim instance. When the syntastic plugin gets disabled, no such directories are created.

When I ran inotify, I found that a numeric file is created in that directory every time I save a file. Is it possible to make syntastic (or vim) create a temporary directory on demand? Failing on that, can I make it use a single directory instead? For example, `/tmp/vim-syntastic/vXXXXXXX/`?

Comment: Did you ask on Syntastic's issue tracker?

Comment: @romainl Now I did, https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues/1032

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the developer](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues/1032#issuecomment-38252097), syntastic does not create temporary directories by itself, that is handled by vim. Looking a bit further, I found that `vim` uses `$TMPDIR` to set a temporary directory. If the directory is unwritable, then it gets ignored.

So, as a solution, the following lines set the temporary directory to `/tmp/vim-USERNAME`, and then create it (ignoring errors that normally occur when the directory exists):

```
" Keep all vim-related temp files in a single directory
let $TMPDIR = '/tmp/vim-' . $USER
silent! call mkdir($TMPDIR, '', 0700)
```

Now, I do not have a lot of `/tmp/vXXXXXX/` directories anymore. Instead, they appear in `/tmp/vim-peter/vXXXXXX/` which is great.

Comment: This solved my problem, and also gave me a good pointer to solving it for my Windows GVim install. Digging into `syntastic.vim`, I found it was checking for`$TEMP` and `$TMP`, which can be defined in a similar way.

Answer (score 2):

If you look in the syntastic helpfiles, you'll see that syntastic uses a 'tail' file for storing the output of a given make program. You can override the default tail for a given filetype and subchecker by adding the following to your vimrc:

```
let g:syntastic_<filetype>_<subchecker>_tail = "> /tmp/vim-syntastic/your-file-here"
```

So for example if you wanted `mri` to output to `/tmp/vim-syntastic/ruby-mri`, you would write:

```
let g:syntastic_ruby_mri_tail = "> /tmp/vim-syntastic/ruby-mri"
```

See `:help syntastic-config-makeprg` for more info. [Here's a direct link on git](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/blob/master/doc/syntastic.txt#L599). As far as I know there's no built-in way to set the default directory for all syntastic output, unfortunately.

Edit: Lekenstein found another solution, which he posted in the linked Github issue.

```
let $TMPDIR = '/tmp/vim-' . $USER
silent! call mkdir($TMPDIR, '', 0700)
```

This will make a special directory for all vim-related temporary files. That means it will also affect temporary files not related to syntastic.

Comment: Well, the dir is created even if I do not save anything. The file does not even have a fileformat. E.g. `vim /dev/null`. The tail option seems not applicable here.